# I have an error at model fit generator in image captioning task

Tags: model, generator, data-fitting, caption, vgg-net

I am trying to apply image captioning code. I have images with 3 captions for each, so I put my training data. When I run the program, I am facing an error at model.fit_generator().
Do the brackets and single quotations appear in the model summary incorrectly?
[image]

**Here is the error:
**InvalidArgumentError                      Traceback (most recent call last)
 in <cell line: 8>()
8 for i in range(epochs):
9     generator = data_generator(train_descriptions, train_features, tokenizer, max_length)
---> 10     model.fit_generator(generator, epochs=1, steps_per_epoch=steps, verbose=1)
11     model.save('/content/drive/MyDrive/Laren dataset - Copy/model_' + str(i) + '.h5')

2 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/execute.py in quick_execute(op_name, num_outputs, inputs, attrs, ctx, name)
51   try:
52     ctx.ensure_initialized()
---> 53     tensors = pywrap_tfe.TFE_Py_Execute(ctx._handle, device_name, op_name,
54                                         inputs, attrs, num_outputs)
55   except core._NotOkStatusException as e:

InvalidArgumentError: Graph execution error: